# I got an error : Connection Test Failed! Here is what we got instead: -3 Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: odoo-11

i am getting this error while configuration of outgoing email server in odoo
[Screenshort of the outgoing email server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5J4Yy.png)

Comment: Is example@gmail.com your outgoing mail's destination?

Comment: no i just modified it to this

Comment: i have added a correct emailid instead of example@gmail.com

Comment: Enable debugging mode and provide your username and password. Then test connection. What you get?

Comment: After enable the debugging mode and when i click on test connection i got the error as:  Connection Test Failed! Here is what we got instead:
535
5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials q126sm13578583pfq.123 - gsmtp

Comment: Thank u, my problem is solved

Comment: yeah, you're welcome, I did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the SMTP port to `25` and the connection security to `TLS (STARTTLS)`,

[image]

but that doesn't enough to send email from odoo, you have to configure your email account too

1. Navigate to https://myaccount.google.com/
2. Click on Apps with account access
3. Than select 'Allow less secure apps'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please go to **Manage your Google Account** and select **Security**.

[image]

And turn on **2-Step Verification**, after that, you will get the option for **App passwords**

[image]

Now create an **App password** and use that instead of the password in the odoo email configuration settings